# Linux Install on Mac. macOS asks to Initialize

Tags: mac, unix

[image]

Install of Linux on Mac went fine, but I want to get rid of the initialize unreadable popup for the disk after macOS boots. Tried adding the UUIDs in the fstab file but it did not work.

> The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer.
> Initialize... | Ignore | Eject

Do I need the UUID of the disk itself? It's an 80 GB disk dedicated to Linux with 3 partition.

One 1 MB Bios Boot Partition, an EXT4 of 60 GB for Linux Filesystem and a Linux Swap of 15 GB.

I had added the UUIDs of the the three partition as that was all I could get of them.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *240.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         239.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS Refind                  313.3 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +239.5 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     139.4 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 44.7 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                731.4 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 MB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.0 GB    disk1s5

/dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data ExtraWindows            499.9 GB   disk2s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS MAC                     499.1 GB   disk2s3
   4:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk2s4

/dev/disk3 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *750.2 GB   disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Davenpart               250.1 GB   disk3s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS Wellrose                318.1 GB   disk3s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data DOSSER                  181.4 GB   disk3s4

/dev/disk4 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *180.0 GB   disk4
   1:               Windows_NTFS Window 10               179.5 GB   disk4s1
   2:                       0x27                         504.4 MB   disk4s2

/dev/disk5 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *80.0 GB    disk5
   1:        Bios Boot Partition                         1.0 MB     disk5s1
   2:           Linux Filesystem                         65.0 GB    disk5s2
   3:                 Linux Swap                         15.0 GB    disk5s3

lysanderlenihan@Lysanders-Mac-Pro-X ~ %
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot/picture of the message you get? Also, if you still have macOS installed as well, can you run `diskutil list` and add the output to the question.

Comment: edited question with request.

Comment: Try removing the flash drive.

Comment: They are all internal. The APFS is what I think looks like it could be a flash drive

Comment: What is the model/year of the Mac? What type and version of Linux? I ask because the only time I have seen the use of a Bios Boot Partition is when the Mac has a 32 bit EFI.

Comment: The UUID you are referring to is the UUID of the filesystem. If the disk is not readable, then macOS is not going to be able to read the UUID of the file system.

Comment: I  can not post an answer. Apparently, you have Catalina or newer installed, therefore you should have a 64 bit EFI. You should be installing Linux to EFI boot Grub. What you installed is a Linux with a BIOS booting Grub.

Comment: Mint 20 is the Linux. It is a Mac Pro 4,1. I changed the grub to bios in order to use the nvidia driver. I have seen that only version 340 will work so I can try it with efi re-enabled which I had not previously. Had only tried the recommended (440) along with some of the other non bios versions and some set pci in grub

Comment: Then, I would guess that the first partition of `disk5` should be a FAT32 formatted EFI partition. I realize, Grub and Mint would not be using this partition for anything. In other words, use the macOS Disk Utility to erase `disk5` and create a `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` partition. This will create an `EFI` partition. When installing Mint, delete the `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` partition and leave the `EFI` partition.

Comment: The other thought is `disk5` needs at least one partition that macOS can recognize and mount. So create a small `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)`  partition along with the partitions for Grub and Mint. Then you can use the UUID of the `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)`  partition in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: I do not believe that Mac can natively read or write ext3, ext4, etc. partitions that are commonly used on Linux

Answer (score 2):

Having switched the installations grub to EFI and having shrunk the EXT4 partition by 200 mb, creating a fat 32 partition and naming it EFI, the message does not show up anymore.

Additionally, the Nvidia driver works as well in EFI mode. I would not expect though that any of the non bios version drivers would work. 340 is the one marked "bios".

Comment: It would help others, if you could return later and mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Mac is built on BSD Unix.  I thought Linux was Unix on a PC.  So my question is what does Linux get you that Mac Unix can't?

Comment: @jmh, when you have a new question, you should use the “ask question” button.  Not likely to get answers when you use a comment form for a different question.